# JQuery: Remove JS after defining event listener but before listener is triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener

I've got a question that searching did not actually yield any results. I apologize if this has been asked in the past.

I'm trying to define an event listener, and immediately remove the JS after defining the event listener. The problem is, I want the removal to take place prior to the event taking placing. Is this possible? I read in the JQuery 1.4 documentation that `detach()` is like remove, but maintains JQuery data. Is this a viable solution? Are there downsides to removing the code which places an event listener prior to the event taking place?

The code I'm trying to remove is dynamically generated code. Doing something like this:

```
    

    <script id="12341234"> 
        $( function() {
            $('#test').click( function() {
                alert('Hello');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Later in the script:

`$('#12341234').remove();`

That works fine for removing the script, it just doesn't fire the event listener (which makes sense).

The reason I'm trying to do this is for a very small amount of added security. Sensitive fields are already masked, no one can gain access to anything sensitive per se. I just have PHP generating a decent amount of JS, and I don't want the temptation of "inspect element". If they do actually see it, it's not a huge deal. I'd just prefer to remove it if possible.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could look into minification. You couldn't remove actual code in any way that I know of.

Comment: I'm presently removing the code just fine, and minification on-demand adds quite a bit of overhead. The problem isn't being able to remove everything between the specified `<script>` tags, it's being able to remove it without removing the event listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is wondering, I figured out the answer to this.

It functions just as I theorized: It removes the script tags and everything in between, but the event listener remains intact. See below for example:

```
<script id="testscript">
    $( function() {
        $('#testbutton').click( function() {
            alert('Hello!');
        });
    });

    $('#testscript').detach();
</script>
```

This will keep your event-listener, while preventing your JS from being displayed on inspect.

A quick note, if someone is using any sort of debugging tools which can step through rendering, they can EASILY see the code before it's ever removed. However, if you simply don't want the *average user* to see the JS, this will work.

Sensitive data will still need masked or dealt with appropriately.

I still don't know the answer to the question as to whether or not `detach()` has a negative impact, or if it should be avoided for this use-case. However, I did some testing and it doesn't appear to have much performance impact versus `remove()`. We're talking 1% slower or less. I also dug a bit more through documentation, and reaffirmed my initial believe that my use-case is basically a standard use-case for `detach()`. There doesn't seem to be any downside to using it. I may be wrong, and if so feel free to correct me.